# Expected CSRF token not found. Error 403

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have a Spring web application using Spring Security 3.2. Initially I was authenticating users against in-memory credentials. My Security configuration file was:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
      .and()
        .logout()
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
      .and()
      .rememberMe()
        .tokenRepository(new InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl())
        .tokenValiditySeconds(2419200)
        .key("spittrKey")
      .and()
       .httpBasic()
         .realmName("Spittr")
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("spitter/me").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/spittles").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password("secman").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("mike").password("secman").roles("USER");
  }

}
```

Part of my application has a page to create a new account:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Spitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      th:href="@{/resources/styles.css}"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header" th:include="page :: header"></div>

    <div id="content">
      <h1>Register</h1>

      <form method="POST" th:object="${spitter}">
        <div class="errors" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
             <h3 color="red">Please fix the following errors:</h3>
          <ul class="errsul">
            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" 
                th:text="${err}">Input is incorrect</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <label th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}? 'error'">First Name</label>:
          <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"  
             th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}? 'error'" /><br/>             

        <label th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}? 'error'">Last Name</label>:
          <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
             th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}? 'error'" /><br/>

        <label th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'error'">Email</label>:
          <input type="text" th:field="*{email}"
             th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'error'" /><br/>

        <label th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'error'">Username</label>:
          <input type="text" th:field="*{username}"
             th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'error'" /><br/>

        <label th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'error'">Password</label>:
          <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"  
             th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'error'" /><br/>

        <label>Confirm Password</label>:
          <input type="password" th:field="*{confirmPassword}" /><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Register" />

      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" th:include="page :: copy"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Loggin in as role USER or ADMIN worked fine as did creating a new account. I'm not showing the controllers as I don't think they are relevant to my question. I changed the security configuration so that I am now authenticating against the account table in the MySQL database. The change to SecutrityConfig.java is in the configure method:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .jdbcAuthentication()
          .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled"
                                   +" from account where username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select a.username, r.name from account a,"
                                        +" role r, account_role ar where ar.account_id = a.id" 
                                        +" and ar.role_id = r.id and a.username = ?");

  }
```

And of course, I also autowire my dataSource as a private attribute in SecurityConfig.java. When I changed to jdbc-based authentication, I suddenly started getting the CSRF null exception when submitting my form to register a new account. Per other stackoverflow postings on this issue, I had to add the following to my registration form:

```
      <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

This solved the problem. I know using the spring tag library will automatically do the above for you, as will using

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/....}"/>
```

on your form, but I was not using either. My form submission URL is implied by the URL used in a GET request to display the form. So my question is, the only change I made was in going from in-memory authentication to jdbc-based authentication. The only change I made was the above change to SecurityConfig.java. In doing so, it seems that CSRF filtering went from inactive to active. Does this sound correct? I could not find anything on the Spring Security documentation page to indicate this.

Comment: this is strange that changing from in-memory authentication to jdbc authentication will activate CSRF..so do you want to disable it?

Comment: No, I don't want to disable it, I do know how to do so. I'm just trying to make sense out of what happened. I thought CSRF was active by default as of Security 2.3 when using Java configuration. This seems to indicate for some reason it was not active, at least until I went to jdbc authentication. I can't think of any other change I made that would affect CSRF.